# php json_encode convert wrong date

Tags: php, json

I need to send data in **json format**, but to convert the date it loses the original formatting:

```
 $date =   date("d/m/Y", "1988-12-04 00:00:00");
 $teste = json_encode($date);
 var_dump($teste);exit;
```

I need this format:  `04/12/1988`, but print: string `"01\/01\/1970"`
(length=14)

How to remove this bar?

Comment: [read the docs on `date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), noting the second argument

Comment: Second argument of `date` is a timestamp, and you have a string.

Comment: See: [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Use [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem with `json_encode()`? What do you see if you `var_dump($date)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `strtotime` while changing date format.

```
$date =   date("d/m/Y", strtotime("1988-12-04 00:00:00"));
 $teste = json_encode($date);
 var_dump($teste);exit;
```